# Subspace described by solution set of homogenous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

> Let $U\subset\mathbb{Q}^4$ be the subspace induced by the following vectors: $$u_1=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 6 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \;u_2=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;u_3=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Compute the dimension of $U$ and find a homogeneous system of linear equations over $\mathbb{Q}$ with as few equations as possible, such that its solution set is $U$.

I've used Gaussian elimination and found out that $U$ has dimension $3$, hence $u_1,u_2,u_3$ form a basis of $U$.  
**My problem:** I haven't been able to find the according linear system and I have no idea how I should proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\dim U=3$ and $\dim\mathbb Q^4=4$, $U$ is a hyperplane, and therefore you can solve your problem with a system which consists of a single equation. One such equation is $-3x+z+5t=0$. Actually, any equation of the type $ax+by+cz+dt=0$ will do as long as$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a+2b+6c=0\\2a-b+c+d=0\\-a+2c-d=0\end{array}\right.$$and $(a,b,c,d)\neq(0,0,0,0)$ (that's how I got my solution).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but how did you come up with $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a+2b+6c=0\\2a-b+c+d=0\\-a+2c-d=0\end{array}\right.$$?

Comment: Don't you recognise the coefficients? The coefficients of the first equation are $2$, $2$, $6$, and $0$, whereas $u_1=(2,2,6,0)^T$. And so on…

Comment: Yes, I recognise them, but I'm still struggling to understand how making the linear combination of coefficients equal zero gives us the solution.

Comment: What you're after are numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is one of your vectors, then $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4=0$. That way, you will be sure that each of you vectors is a solution of the system. That's what you want, right?!

Comment: thank you very much, that made it click for me.

Comment: actually, it didn't, as I just noticed. I still can't seem to understand why our solution set is $U$, since, for example, how is $u_1$ a solution?

Comment: Because $U$ is spanned by $u_1$, $u_2$ , and $u_3$. So, since these $3$ vectors are solutions of the system, the space that they span is a subset of the space of solutions. And since both spaces have dimension $3$, they are equal.

Comment: But that's just the problem for me: Why are $u_1, u_2, u_3$ solutions? Since $u_1$ doesn't even fulfil the first equation, as $2\cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 + 6^2\neq 0$.

Comment: I want that, if $(x,y,z,t)=(2,2,6,0)(=u_1)$, then $ax+by+cz+dt=0$. What what *this* means is that $2a+2b+6c=0$.

Comment: Ohh, yes thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solve $2a+2b+6c=0\tag1$

$2a-b+c+d=0\tag2$

$-a+2c-d=0.\tag3$.

From (1), $a+b+3c=0$, and from (2)+(3), $a-b+3c=0$; so $b=0$.

Thus $a=-3c$ and $d=5c$.

So $\vec v\cdot \vec u=0,$ where $\vec v$ is any multiple of $(-3,0,1,5)$.